# Qt Creator & Kinect: error: C1083: Cannot open include file: 'NuiApi.h'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, kinect

I'm trying to build a Kinect App with a GUI, so naturally I choose to use Qt. I followed the Kinect example "[Color Basic-D2D](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh973080.aspx)" provided by Kinect developer toolkits and I ran the example in Visual Studio 2010, which worked out fine. However, when I exported the project into Qt creator and trying running it there, I got the following error:

C:\KinectProjects\ColorBasics-D2D\ColorBasics.h:10: error: C1083: Cannot open include file: 'NuiApi.h': No such file or directory

And here is my .pro file:

```
# ----------------------------------------------------
# This file is generated by the Qt Visual Studio Add-in.
# ------------------------------------------------------

TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = ColorBasics-D2D
DESTDIR = ./Debug
QT += core multimedia opengl widgets gui sensors concurrent multimediawidgets
CONFIG += debug
DEFINES += _WINDOWS QT_MULTIMEDIA_LIB QT_OPENGL_LIB QT_SENSORS_LIB QT_WIDGETS_LIB QT_CONCURRENT_LIB QT_MULTIMEDIAWIDGETS_LIB
INCLUDEPATH += $(NOINHERIT)
LIBS += -L"$(NOINHERIT)" \
    -lkernel32 \
    -luser32 \
    -lwinspool \
    -lcomdlg32 \
    -ladvapi32 \
    -lshell32 \
    -lole32 \
    -loleaut32 \
    -luuid \
    -lodbc32 \
    -lodbccp32 \
    -lKinect10 \
    -lopengl32 \
    -lglu32

DEPENDPATH += .
MOC_DIR += ./GeneratedFiles/debug
OBJECTS_DIR += debug
UI_DIR += ./GeneratedFiles
RCC_DIR += ./GeneratedFiles
include(ColorBasics-D2D.pri)
```

And here is how the include looks like in ColorBasic.h:

```
#pragma once

#include "resource.h"
#include "NuiApi.h"
#include "ImageRenderer.h"

class CColorBasics
{
    static const int        cColorWidth  = 640;
    static const int        cColorHeight = 480;

        static const int        cStatusMessageMaxLen = MAX_PATH*2;

    public:
        CColorBasics();
        ~CColorBasics();
        static LRESULT CALLBACK MessageRouter(...);
        LRESULT CALLBACK        DlgProc(...);

        int                     Run(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow);

    private:
        HWND                    m_hWnd;

        bool                    m_bSaveScreenshot;

        // Current Kinect
        INuiSensor*             m_pNuiSensor;

        // Direct2D
        ImageRenderer*          m_pDrawColor;
        ID2D1Factory*           m_pD2DFactory;
        HANDLE                  m_pColorStreamHandle;
        HANDLE                  m_hNextColorFrameEvent;
        void                    Update();
        HRESULT                 CreateFirstConnected();
        void                    ProcessColor();
        void                    SetStatusMessage(WCHAR* szMessage);
        HRESULT                 SaveBitmapToFile();
    };
```

I have compared it with my visual studio's library path and they all have the correct libraries linked. It seems I need to put a include path after the "INCLUDEPATH" line. So what should it be? I trying putting the path for NuiApi.h there but it still has the same error. Or is the error due to a different thing? I'm using Qt5.5. Thanks!

Comment: Post the actual `#include` line from your code. It's possible there is a path component, and you need to add one of the parent directories to `INCLUDEPATH`.

Comment: Updated! See code above

Comment: Might not matter, but try changing `#include "NuiApi.h"` to `#include <NuiApi.h>`, and placing the path to the header in `INCLUDEPATH`. The file in quotes could mean "search relative to the current directory (the directory of the file being compiled)", while the angle brackets mean "system header file". Note that some compilers might not make the distinction the same way. Also, does the path to the header contain any spaces and if so are you accounting for this in your project file?